# Is there a general way to delay computing & displaying mode-line text?

Tags: mode-line, idle-timer

Some things I'd like to show in the mode-line are quite expensive to compute, so I'd rather use an idle timer.

Is there a general way to do this? or does this need to be added individually? (using a method similar to `which-function-mode`, for example).

Comment: Here is what I did a few years ago as a workaround and have been happily using it ever since:  Use a `pre-command-hook` and a `post-command-hook` to record (for purposes of comparison) four (4) values each command loop:  `this-command`; `last-command`; the currently `(selected-window)`; and, the *previously* `(selected-window)`.  Set up a set of rules regarding which commands have a high rate of repetition; e.g., `undo` / `redo`; `left-char` / `right-char`; `scroll-up` / `scroll-down`; etc...  [To be continued in the following comment hereinbelow.]

Comment: Continuation:  If `this-command` is `eq` to `last-command` and the current command is a `memq` of the list of the aforementioned high rate of repetition commands, then use a pre-recorded value for the expensive command.  When the aforementioned situation is *not* happening, anything that is expensive gets calculated and stored to a variable using `format-mode-line` to convert it to a string, which can contain colors as well as other properties for mouse-over help, etc.  When the aforementioned condition exists, the stored values are used for the expensive components of the mode-line.

Comment: Continuation:  Here is the function I use for the `post-command-hook`:  `(defun ml-post-command-hook-fn () (setq ml-selected-window--post-command-hook (selected-window)))`  Here is the function I use for the `pre-command-hook`:  `(defun ml-pre-command-hook-fn () (setq ml-selected-window--pre-command-hook (selected-window)) (setq ml-this-command this-command) (setq ml-last-command last-command))`.  These values can also be used to differentiate the mode-line in the `selected-window` versus a `non-selected` window, so the colors and so forth for the components can be different; e.g., dim / bold.

Comment: Continuation:  If changing colors in the mode-line for the `mode-line` face and the `mode-line-inactive` face and the `minibuffer-prompt` face to better distinguish between a selected window versus a non-selected window -- in conjunction with the method described in the previous comments -- be sure to use the `face-remapping-alist` instead of expensive functions such as `set-face-attribute` and the like.  Use methods such as `setq-default` and `setq-local` ...  The manual suggests using `face-remap-add-relative` instead of directly controlling the `face-remapping-alist`, but I am adventurous.

Comment: Continuation:  Be aware that `this-command` and `last-command` have a short shelf-life, which is why it must be recorded and that recorded value is used when the `mode-line` is being computed / updated; i.e., when comparing `ml-this-command` to `ml-last-command`.  When the `mode-line` is computed / updated the `(selected-window)` also changes, which why it is necessary to use the recorded values instead for comparison purposes; i.e., `ml-selected-window--post-command-hook` versus `ml-selected-window--pre-command-hook` (both of which are custom global variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using idle timers, although this can get a little involved if you have multiple idle timers and want to prevent them setting each other off.

I've wrapped this up into a small package: [mode-line-idle](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-mode-line-idle), a small dedicated package which does just this, without any configuration or minor-modes.

Calls to the main function can be done in `:eval` blocks in the `mode-line-format` variable.